# CCSprite initializer causes crash with no exception or error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a custom `CCSprite` class to display a custom image and set its own position as well as handle other drawing tasks.  Currently I have no other code running in the custom class but the initializer, which should set the image file and the position of the sprite.  Here is my `- (id)init` method

```
- (id)init 
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFile:@"runnerImage.png"]))
        return nil;
    //set our texture to the runner image ^^^
    //set our initial position
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height-RUNNER_OFFSET); //centered x and offseted by RUNNER_OFFSET
    return self;
}
```

Currently the app crashes after running this code. (I have determined this with break points and commenting out lines.)  Any idea why? This is the section I am calling it from:

```
myRunner = [[Runner alloc] init];
[self addChild:myRunner];   
//schedule an update each frame
```

That is in a `CCLayer` subclass's `- init` method.

Here is the console log:

> 2010-07-31 09:16:32.730
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: cocos2d
>   v0.99.4-rc2 2010-07-31 09:16:32.733
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: Using
>   Director Type:CCDisplayLinkDirector
>   2010-07-31 09:16:33.064
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:
>   Apple Computer, Inc. 2010-07-31
>   09:16:33.065 CubeRacer[849:207]
>   cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software
>   Renderer 2010-07-31 09:16:33.065
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d:
>   GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
>   2010-07-31 09:16:33.066
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d:
>   GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048 2010-07-31
>   09:16:33.067 CubeRacer[849:207]
>   cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH:
>   16 2010-07-31 09:16:33.068
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: GL
>   supports PVRTC: YES 2010-07-31
>   09:16:33.068 CubeRacer[849:207]
>   cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888
>   textures: NO 2010-07-31 09:16:33.071
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: GL
>   supports NPOT textures: YES 2010-07-31
>   09:16:33.072 CubeRacer[849:207]
>   cocos2d: GL supports
>   discard_framebuffer: YES 2010-07-31
>   09:16:33.072 CubeRacer[849:207]
>   cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support:
>   NO 2010-07-31 09:16:33.073
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: compiled
>   with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
>   2010-07-31 09:16:33.074
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: compiled
>   with Affine Matrix transformation in
>   CCNode : YES 2010-07-31 09:16:33.074
>   CubeRacer[849:207] cocos2d: compiled
>   with Profiling Support: NO Program
>   received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

*Thanks for any help!*

**Update**
After some more research I found this may be a looping problem but I am unsure.
The superclasses initializer that I am calling calls `[self init]`.  Would that call the `- (id)init` method of my subclass or of the `CCSprite` class?  If it calls my subclass then that is the obvious problem.  Check my comment for a link to the discussion I found of this.

Comment: I found another description of this problem saying it is a looping issue. Apparently the super initializers for CCSprite call [self init] again, calling my subclasses initializer if I am right.  That would cause an issue correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your method is the designated initializer -(id) init and then you call [super initWithFile:..] in it, which in turn calls -(id) init. Now because you have overridden -(id) init in your implementation, your version gets called and you'll have an endless loop.

That's as far as I understand it. It's definetely a bad idea to call a super method other than [super init] in the -(id) init method. Instead, rename your -(id) init method to -(id) initWithRunnerImage and you should be fine.

The Apple docs give some more examples:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW8